# Printing Certain values of Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm creating a small program that populates a Linked List from a txt file and then I want to do some manipulation on the Linked List before saving it back to file.

However, I'm slightly confused as to how I access the nodes of the linked list I've created - and how I can loop through the list and print only certain nodes (e.g. the first and last name only).

**Linked List Structure**

```
struct EmployeeLL
{
    string position;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string startDate;
    float empNumber;
    string deptartment;
    float salary;
    float hourlyRate;
    float hoursPerWeek;

    EmployeeLL *link;
};
```

**Loading the Linked List:**

```
void loadLinkedList()
{
    fstream in("payroll.txt", ios::in);

    string position, first, last, date, dept;
    float salary, rate, week, emp;

    EmployPtr head = new EmployeeLL;

    while (in >> position >> first >> last >> date >> emp >> dept >> salary >> rate >> week)
    {
        cout << position << ", " << first << ", " << last << ", " << date << ", " << emp << ", " << dept << ", " << salary << ", " << rate << ", " << week << endl;
        insertAtHead(head, position, first, last, date, emp, dept, salary, rate, week);
    }

    in.close();
}
```

**Inserting the read values into the Linked List**

```
void insertAtHead(EmployPtr& head, string positionValue, string firstNameValue, string lastNameValue, string startDateValue, float empValue, string deptValue,
    float salaryValue, float hourlyRateValue, float hoursPerWeekValue)
{
    EmployPtr tempPtr = new EmployeeLL;
tempPtr->position = positionValue;
tempPtr->firstName = firstNameValue;
tempPtr->lastName = lastNameValue;
tempPtr->startDate = startDateValue;
tempPtr->empNumber = empValue;
tempPtr->deptartment = deptValue;
tempPtr->salary = salaryValue;
tempPtr->hourlyRate = hourlyRateValue;
tempPtr->hoursPerWeek = hoursPerWeekValue;

tempPtr->link = head;
head = tempPtr;
}
```

Here's where I get confused. I want to know how I can print (for example) the first and last names of everyone in the linked list?

Here's the code I've attempted so far:

```
void printNames(EmployPtr& head)
{
    EmployeeLL* thisNode = head;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        cout << "The list is empty\n";
        return;
    }
    else
        cout << "---------------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "\tFirstName\tLastName\n";
    cout << "---------------------------------------------------------\n";

    do
    {
        cout << setw(8) << left << thisNode->firstName;
        cout << setw(16) << left << thisNode->lastName;
        cout << "\n\t";


    } while (thisNode != NULL);
    {
        cout << "\n\n";
    }

}
```

Comment: what is wrong with your attempt ? Does it compile? Does it run? Does it produce some output? And please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Make your life easier by just using `std::list`. Or, in fact, `std::vector`, which should be your default, as often it provides all that's needed, in which case it is better in many ways: more cache-efficient, random-access, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are *three* problems. The two first in the `loadLinkedList` function:

1. You should not create the initial `EmployeeLL` node that you initialize `head` to point to. You should initialize `head` as a null pointer:

   ```
   EmployPtr head = nullptr;
   ```
2. You don't return the list you create from the function. Once `loadLinkedList` returns the list is lost forever.
3. In the loop in the `printNames` function, you never change where `thisNode` points. You never iterate over the list, instead you have an infinite loop printing the first node in the list over and over.

Comment: Is returning the linked list as simple as: "return EmployeeLL;"? And do I need to change the return type from void? If so, what do I change it to?

Comment: @GuestUser140561 No you return the pointer to the first node (`head`). And yes you need to change the return type accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing moving to the next node.

```
...
thiNode = thisNode->link;   //move to the next node
} while (thisNode != NULL);
```